# How to download kaggle datasets from Paperspace Free GPU's

Tags: python, data-science, kaggle

How to download kaggle datasets usingkaggle API from paperspace free GPU....?
 I used below code in colab it works fine....but when I use same code in Paperspace free Gpu's it shows 404 not found error
can anyone help me on this  how to download kaggle datasets from paperspace free GPU's.....

```
#uploading kaggle API 
from google.colab import files 
files.upload()
#checking api
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle 
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json 
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json 
#downloading data from API
!kaggle competitions download -c malware-classification
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help 8) Kaggle CLI - Dataset Downloads Ref https://gist.github.com/ksferguson/0b384e892689617d1539d35c1254eb01

Comment: Thanks, I find a way to download in a single line checkout this video this way was awesome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPUfVq7RaY8